# How can I compute MD5 hash of "a" in C#?

Tags: c#

I tried to practice C# programming. I tried to compute the MD5.has of a string "a". But how to fix this code as it outputs 4144e195f46de78a3623da7364d04f11 instead of 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661?

```
//Title of this code
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a="a";
            Console.WriteLine(CalculateMD5Hash(a));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
        {
            using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
            {
                byte[] retval = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i=0;i<retval.Length;++i)
                {
                    sb.Append(retval[i].ToString("x2"));
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the encodings of text the same?

Comment: Indeed: hash algorithms generally work on *binary* data, not text. You're converting text to bytes here: `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input)`. My guess is that using `Encoding.Utf8` instead of `Encoding.Unicode` will give you the answer you want, but you need to understand that the MD5 hash of "a" is not defined, precisely *because* "a" is text, not bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain `0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661` you just need to use `Encoding.UTF8`.

```
using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
{
    byte[] hashValue = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in hashValue)
        sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Please check out the fact that .NET use [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) to encode strings.